# SwiftUI: List does not display the data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I tried to display the data of my server, the items appear and then disappeared a second after what?

Yet I'm displaying a static list that works ..

Look at the start of the video the bottom list:
[image]

My code:

```swift
struct HomeView: View {

    @EnvironmentObservedResolve private var viewModel: HomeViewModel
    var test = ["", ""]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(
                    action: {
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("My Button")
                    }
            )

            List(test, id: \.self) { el in
                Text("Work")
            }
            List(viewModel.items) { el in
                Text("\(el.id)") // Not work
            }
        }
                .padding()
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.getData()
                }
    }
}
```

My viewModel:

```swift
class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {

    private let myRepository: MyRepository

    @Published var items: [Item] = []


    init(myRepository: MyRepository) {
        self.myRepository = myRepository
    }

}

@MainActor extension HomeViewModel {

    func getData() {
        Task {
            items = try await myRepository.getData()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what's `@EnvironmentObservedResolve` and where does `emergencyRepository` in `extension HomeViewModel ` comes from.
Are you showing us code that you are not using?

Comment: A `@EnvironmentObservedResolve` It's my DI pattern. You just hit. In my DI I set this `viewModel` instance type `new` and as `swiftui` view is a `struct` each time changes observed it destroys the view. Apparently it's not good practice for the `viewModel` to be `singleton`. So it's the repository that must maintain the arrays

Comment: sorry mate, but I don't understand what this is about. Why can't you have `@StateObject var viewModel = HomeViewModel()` 
up in your hierarchy, and pass it to the `HomeView` using `@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: HomeViewModel`.
Maybe you could show what this `@EnvironmentObservedResolve` is and how you pass it to  `HomeView`.

Comment: Thank you! `@EnvironmentObservedResolve` wrapped `@ObservedObject` for my DI. The `@StateObject` was the solution, so created also `@StateObjectResolve` for my DI.